# Eclipse CDT project built but "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found"

Tags: eclipse-cdt, binaries

Windows 7, Eclipse CDT, Juno Service Release 2, Cross compiler.

Projects do compile executables generated, but Eclipse can't see them; therefore 'Run' fails. Executables are placed in Debug directory. Double click or command prompt call on compiled executable works without problem.

[image]

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: None of these solutions helped me. I've had to delete the folder and redo the project. Does anybody have another solution that may be my issue?

Comment: Its because eclipse cant find your .exe file after linking is done. Just point to your project's exe file under Run Configurations... as suggested below and browse to your exe file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I found solution - proper binary parser must be selected so Eclipse can recognize the executable:

**Select the project, then right-click. Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers, PE Windows Parser.**

I.e. if Cygwin compiler is used then Cygwin parser should be used.

That worked for me at least for Cross-compiler (both on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04). On Linux, I use **Elf** parser.

If anyone has the better solution, please advise.

Comment: Works for me, with Eclipse Kepler for c\c++ and MinGw installed and in Windows 7 Path

Answer (score 53):

This happened to me and I found a solution, see if this works for you:

Once you have built your project with the hammer icon:

1. select "Run".
2. Run Configurations.
3. Choose "C++ Application".
4. Click on the "New Launch Configuration" icon on the top left of the open window.
5. Select "Browse" under the C/C++ Application.
6. Browse to the folder where you made your project initially.
7. Enter the Debug folder.
8. Click on the binary file with the same name as the project.
9. Select "OK".
10. Click "Apply" to confirm the link you just set.
11. Close that window.

Afterwards you should be able to run the project as much as you'd like.

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: I'm using linux and this solution worked for me, thanks. :)

Answer (score 52):

Simply select the project and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: Would be helpful to add that this key combination builds all the projects within Eclipse.

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately. I had to explicitly create a build target.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Eclipse IDE 2018-12. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you - worked for me on Fedora 34 and Eclipse 2021-09.

Answer (score 7):

On a Mac, If you also have a similar problem, as Nenad Bulatovic mentioned above, you need to change the **Binary Parsers**.

Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open up properties (or right click on your project and select property)

Make sure you select **Mach-O 64 Parser**.

[image]

Comment: This worked. After this, "Command + b" to build. Then "Run as -> Local C/C++ Application".

Answer (score 4):

press ctrl +B and then You can use the Run button.

Answer (score 3):

first i had to click a little arrow button that opens a menu containing "Run Configurations", 
[image]

then in the following window, i had to click "C/C++ Application", followed by a textless button with a green + on it
 [image]

then i had to press the "Apply" and "Run" button
[image]

and then eclipse could run/debug the program. :)

Answer (score 2):

in my case this is the solution to fix it. When you create a project select MinGW GCC from the Toolchains panel.

[image]

Once the project is created, select project file, press ctrl + b to build the project. Then hit run and the the output should be printed on the console.

Comment: Underrated answer, IMO. This creates defaults that serve as a good starting place. You may need to uncheck the "Show project types and toolchains..." checkbox to have the "MinGW GCC" option appear.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had this problem - and the cause was invalid DWARF 3 info in the binary in the selected project (which didn't have any runnable binaries).

The way it work was something like this: I had two projects `Main` and `Library`. `Main` depended on the `Library` project and the former had an executable, while the latter just produced a static library (that `Main` linked against).

My run option was set to "Run/Debug -> Launch" setting was set to "launch current, otherwise last" as follows (see bottom right):

[image: Run/Debug settings]

If I had the `Main` project selected, everything would work fine: it would launch the main project. If I had the `Library` project selected<sup>1</sup> it would fail with the error message given by the OP. The reason seemed to be this: since I had the `Library` project selected, the PE scanner would scan the binary files in the project to see if any were launchable, and because scanning was failing [due to this bug](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1084550/) the error message popped up before it ever got to "Launch the previously launched application".

I could work around it by:

1. Making sure the project I wanted to launch was selected, or ...
2. Changing compilers to one that made DWARF info that Eclipse could parse without failure, or ...
3. Selecting "Always launch the previously launched application" in the Run/Debug settings - although it might not be your preferred mode of operation.

---

<sup>1</sup> I wouldn't usually select the project directly, of course, it would be indirectly selected because I was working in one of the source files it contained.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that after building your project (`CTRL+B`), you need to create a run (or debug) configuration in the `Run` or `Debug` dropdown menu from the main toolbar. Then in the main page, click the

`Search Project...`

button.

This will find all executable files you have built and show them in a dialog box. You can choose the right one and then hit the Run (or

Answer (score 1):

If you have a successful build, and getting a "Launch Binary not Found" Error. Try doing the following steps :

Click on Run -> Run Configuration -> C/C++ Application -> click on project_name debug -> click on browse and select your project file -> Press Ok -> below it Browse binary file ( Goto your Eclipse Workspace and select your project file -> You'll find two files 1.Debug 2.Src -> Click on Debug file -> Next click on the file with your project name and Press ok) -> then click apply and press run button.

This should solve the problem

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Go to Project --> Properties --> Run/Debug Settings --> Click on the configuration & click "Edit", it will now open a "Edit Configuration".

Hit on "Search Project" , select the binary file from the "Binaries" and hit ok.

Note : Before doing all this, make sure you have done the below

--> Binary is generated once you execute "Build All" or (Ctrl+B)

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything here what worked for me was to grant execution permission to eclipse:

```
cd eclipse-installation-dir 
sudo chmod +x eclipse
```

Using Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the folder name does not contain .c extension. When I removed the .c extension in my folder name it worked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the MinGW compiler when running the code. Failure to do this will cause the launch failed binary not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on Eclipse 3.8.1. For me it worked to set the artifact type to executable:

**Right click on the project -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Artifact -> Artifact Type: Executable**

Finally rebuilding the project produced the Binaries entry in the Project Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

The video link below illustrate these steps in more detail:

1. Create Empty project
2. Choose linux Gcc compiler
3. Right click on project choose " source folder "
4. Name it " src "
5. Right click on src folder choose " source file "
6. Start coding
7. Save project
8. Build project
9. Run project

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtyBvagV-_A