# Launch falied : binary not found

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run Hello World (C++) program in eclipse on Ubuntu OS. I am getting the error

Launch Failed : Binary not found.

I build the project . But, it's not working.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Which program? Java or C++ or ...?

Comment: Maybe this could **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023235/eclipse-cdt-project-builded-but-launch-failed-binary-not-found)** answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the binary parser to GNU Elf Parser. You can change this in the Project preferences / C/C++ Build / Settings / Binary Parsers tab. Try with different binary parsers, maybe your system is different to mine.