# Starting with C using eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

I wanted to start programming with C, just because it is still important, and you need it for many study paths.
So i used eclipse before for programming java (just basics), and saw that you can use it for c/c++ too by installing other features. But I don't understand how to get it working, i tried several guides, but they were all outdated. I don't know how to link a compiler to eclipse, or whatelse I need.

ps: Sorry if my english may sound a little odd, I'm from germany.

Comment: You might want to start from finding C compiler(s) and install it. If you've already done this I think there's a lot of guides to link your compiler with eclipse. Don't forget that you'll need C/C++ package installed, or use the C/C++ edition of eclipse.

Comment: Check out the following link.
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Comment: I believe CDT can *detect* a proper installation of MinGW gcc toolchain.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @GRC Windows 8 64bit

Comment: Have you tried what Amit posted above?

Comment: @GRC Yes, but if I try to run the program, it says "launch failed. Binary not found"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT project built but "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023235/eclipse-cdt-project-built-but-launch-failed-binary-not-found)

Comment: check this out!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023235/eclipse-cdt-project-built-but-launch-failed-binary-not-found click **CTL + B**

Comment: yeah my suggestion is close this question since it has many many questions already answer.

Comment: @GRC ok, I think I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

please follow this link you can download 
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunar